# jqplot: hide duplicate cursor position from second y axis

Tags: jqplot

I have a graph in JQPlot, however, since I have two y-axis, I have two cursor plots, the second one doesn't really offer any useful information.
[image]

Does anyone know how I can change this to just display one e.g. Tue 16:46, 16
Or alternatively, just show the x-axis e.g. Tue 16:46 and not display the y-axis at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [$.jqplot.Cursor.tooltipAxisGroups](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-cursor-js.html#$.jqplot.Cursor.tooltipAxisGroups) property solves this task. Just assign the array of axis names to display, like

```
cursor: {
  tooltipAxisGroups: [['xaxis']]
}
```

Look at JSFiddle: [jqPlot tooltipAxisGroups demo](https://jsfiddle.net/apdevelop/yz5p803w/)